# The shortest path length between neighbors of connected vertices (not any two random vertices!)

Tags: python, algorithm, networkx, igraph, shortest-path

I asked previously a similar question but, as I think, it was not clear. I have an undirected and unweighted graph of `10000` vertices and around `5000000` edges which I read them to python as an edge list.

In my work, I am trying to build a function from each edge that depends on the distances between the neighbor of vertices on each edge. Suppose we have two connected vertices v1, v2 represent an edge, for v1 there are n1 connected neighbors and there are also n2 neighbors connected to v2. In order to build my function, I need to get the distances between the n1 and n2 neighbors. For all edges in the graph, the function looks like:

```
e_1*d_1 +e_1*d_2 +...+e_1*d_n+...e_m*d_1+...e_m*d_n
```

where n is the number of neighbors for both vertices on each edge, d_n is the distance between that vertices, m is the number of edges in the graph and e_m is the last edge in that graph.

Normally, if we want to get the shortest path length we think about graph traversing like Dijkstra's Algorithm or Bfs especially that my graph is unweighted. I used many functions already written in packages like `networkx` and `igraph` but these functions are not efficient and consuming a lot of time for my graph. For example the function `shortest_paths_dijkstra()`takes around 6.9 hours to get the distance because I need to call it many many times. Also the function `all_pairs_shortest_path _length` takes around 13 minutes (by fixing the path length known as cutoff to 3) and another 16 minutes for calling the distance for each pair of neighbors in the graph!

As written in the question we need to get the distance between the neighbors of v1, v2 so the maximum distance is 3 since the v1, v2 are connected. I feel that there is a more clever solution to reduce the time complexity by using the fact that the possible distances for a path (in my case) are `0, 1, 2, 3` since so I don't need to traverse the whole graph for each path between a source and a target! just I am looking for a clever way to get the distance between the neighbors (not any two randomly vertices)!

I wrote this code but it takes a lot of time, around 54 minutes so it is not efficient also!

```
neighbor1 = {}
neighbor2 = {}
distance = {}
for i in list(edges.values()):
  list_of_distances = []
  neighbor1 = tuple(graph.vs[graph.neighbors(i[0], mode="all")]["name"])
  neighbor2 = tuple(graph.vs[graph.neighbors(i[1], mode="all")]["name"])
  for n2 in neighbor2:
    for n1 in neighbor1:
       if n1 == n2:
            list_of_distances.append(0)
       elif (n1 != n2) and not graph.are_connected(n1,n2):
            if ( graph.are_connected(i[0],n2) ) or ( graph.are_connected(n1,i[1])  ): 
               list_of_distances.append(2)
            elif ( not graph.are_connected(i[0],n2)  ) or ( not graph.are_connected(n1,i[1]) ):
               list_of_distances.append(3)
       else:
            list_of_distances.append(1)
  distance[tuple(i)] = list_of_distances
```

I would like to know if there is another way which doesn't need a lot of memory and time to get these distances or if it is possible to modify one the graph traverse methods like Bfs or Dijkstra so it is not necessary to search the whole graph each iteration and just to do something local(if it is possible to say). Thanks for any help

Comment: Define the function you are after: arguments, return value.

Comment: If `Vx` and `Vy` are (directly) connected what is the distance between them? How do you get a distance of zero?

Comment: @wwii  `Vx==Vy`.

Comment: @wwii the distance between any two vertices represent an edge in the graph is fixed to be 1 since they are connected. In fact I don't compute the distance between those vertices but instead I need to get the distance between their neighbors so if both vertices have a common neighbor then the distance is 0

Comment: Your function is a bit unclear, what is the value of e_1 and such? Maybe adding the code you use to calculate it would help

Comment: @juvian the function itself is not important in this question. In fact it is a too long code consists of many parts but I only have a problem in getting the distance. More precisely it is an optimization problem and I need to read this information(distance between neighbors) from the graph and then to use it again in a different place in the complete code so there are no other options instead of getting the distance. As I said the PROBLEM is how to get the distance efficiently!

Comment: Your approach is also what I would do. Have you profiled what takes the most time? It might be the `graph.are_connected` call, depending on how it is implemented. Or maybe simply memory allocation. You have around 1000 neighbors per vertex, i.e. you want to calculate 1M numbers per edge, that is a total of five trillion numbers. Naturally, that takes a while. There may be optimizations depending on your specific function.

Comment: @NicoSchertler The distances represents the objective function so, up to my knowledge, I should include them. In fact you are right about the consumed time, it is a result of reasons you described. I can't deal with the second issue but I am thinking about replacing the function  ` are_connected ` (although it is the best) but I didn't find an alternative yet

Comment: Try meassuring time by doing nothing in the inner loop, just a pass after the for n1 in neighbor1 line

Comment: I'm pretty sure your function is missing a significant component: It only checks for connection between neighbors n1 and n2 at distance 2 via the endpoints of the given edge (i[0] and i[1]) - but n1 and n2 may be connected by another point entirely . I believe you need to check for overlap between the neighbors of n1 and the neighbors of n2, which of course will make things that much slower. On the plus side, you don't need to do any check for distance 3, because you already know n1 and n2 are at most 3 apart.

Comment: You might be able to improve the speed dramatically by caching the distance between each pair of vertices as you calculate it. Some simplistic modeling suggests that in running this function for each edge you're calculating the distance between each pair of vertices tens of thousands of times.

Comment: One final consideration - depending on your graph structure a lot of this work may be unnecessary. I created a random graph with 10,000 vertices and 5 million edges and sampled 1 million pairs of vertices - _every single pair_ was connected by a path of length 1 or 2. If this is also true for your graph, it may be enough for each pair of vertices to see if they are neighbors and if not, assume they are connected by a path of length 2.

Comment: @NathanVērzemnieks You are completely right, I missed the case if there is a common point between n1 and n2. I tried to solve it yesterday but I couldn't find a procedure to verify if there is a third vertex which is connected to n1 and n2!  Also, unfortunately, I didn't understand how can I improve the speed up to your other comments and why it is possible to not check for the distance 3? Now this function takes 30 minutes so Can you please clarify more or add an answer to improve it up to your comments?

Comment: Compute timings itself has a little sense. What processor do you have? Because if you have some kind of old Core i3 processor, you should not expect times far better than you have now.

Comment: @vurmux I don't think so! I am working on the server of my laboratory...

Comment: Do you know what processor module is in server? I have problems with graph generation like yours in igraph so I can't check is my code is faster than yours.

Comment: @vurmux  $ cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep 'model name' | uniq
model name : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2680 v4 @ 2.40GHz

~$ lscpu
Architecture :                          x86_64
Mode(s) opératoire(s) des processeurs : 32-bit, 64-bit
Boutisme :                              Little Endian
Processeur(s) :                         56

~$ lscpu | grep -i mhz
Vitesse du processeur en MHz :          1200.837
Vitesse maximale du processeur en MHz : 3300,0000
Vitesse minimale du processeur en MHz : 1200,0000

Answer (score 0):

You have extremely computational-heavy task so it is normal that your script is working for hours. You can try to parallelize it with CUDA or with something similar or you can try to construct a large cache (GBs). But if you can't or don't want, I suggest you not to use networkx/igraph functions because they are very slow for you. You can solve your problem without 1000000 DFS runs. Here is one of the possible solutions with Python sets usage (I think it will be faster than yours, maybe not very).

```
import networkx as nx

# Create a graph like yours
G = nx.fast_gnp_random_graph(1000, 0.05)

# Create neighbours dict
G_adj = dict(G.adjacency())
nbrs_dict = {node: {n for n in G_adj[node]} for node in G_adj}

# Result dict
distances = {}

# For every edge:
for e in G.edges:

    # Start value
    dist_value = 0

    # Get N1 and N2 neighbours
    n1_nbrs = nbrs_dict[e[0]]
    n2_nbrs = nbrs_dict[e[1]]

    # Triangles - nodes that connected to both N1 and N2
    # Every triangle value = 0
    tri = n1_nbrs & n2_nbrs
    for t in tri:

        # Get neighbours to find nodes with distance length = 2
        t_nbrs = nbrs_dict[t]

        t_in_n1 = n1_nbrs & t_nbrs
        t_in_n2 = n2_nbrs & t_nbrs

        t_not_in_n1 = n1_nbrs - t_nbrs
        t_not_in_n2 = n2_nbrs - t_nbrs

        dist_value += len(t_in_n1) + len(t_in_n2)
        dist_value += (2 * len(t_not_in_n1)) + (2 * len(t_not_in_n2))

    # Exclude all triangle nodes because we processed them all
    n1nt_nbrs = n1_nbrs - tri
    n2nt_nbrs = n2_nbrs - tri

    # Select squares - nodes with length = 1
    direct = set([])
    for n1 in n1nt_nbrs:
        nbrs = nbrs_dict[n1]
        d = nbrs & n2nt_nbrs
        for node in d:
            direct.add((n1, node))
    dist_value += len(direct)

    # Exclude squares so we have only nodes with length = 3
    n1final = n1nt_nbrs - set(e[0] for e in direct)
    n2final = n2nt_nbrs - set(e[1] for e in direct)
    dist_value += 3 * len(n1final) * len(n2final)

    # Distance for an edge
    distances[e] = dist_value
```

Anyway, your problem has `O(n^3)` complexity so I am highly recommend you to try to split your graph. Maybe you have [bridges](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.bridges.bridges.html#networkx.algorithms.bridges.bridges) or just have several connected components. If you will process them separately, you will incredibly increase your speed.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't analyze your algorithm yet but as a first step I checked the resulted distances and it was strange! I applied th code on this small graph:
1 2
2 3
2 4
3 4
4 5
The resulted dictionary of distances between the neighbors of vertices on each edge should be like this 
{('1', '2'): [1, 1, 1], ('2', '3'): [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0], ('2', '4'): [1, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, 2, 1], ('3', '4'): [0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1], ('4', '5'): [1, 1, 1]} 
while your distances are {('1', '2'): 9, ('2', '3'): 10, ('2', '4'): 13, ('3', '4'): 10, ('4', '5'): 9}? I didn't understand what is going on!

Comment: This algorithm doesn't calculate each possible length separately so I hope it will be faster. It constructs groups of node pairs with each length, multiplies to its length and summarize it. As I understand, you don't need these arrays, you need theirs sum, so this kind of algorithm is applicable.

Comment: Bad news: if you need arrays, my algorithm is useless, you should use yours (maybe with my modifications about neighbours dict, I think it will work a bit faster). In this case I strongly recommend you to try to split your graph because your algorithm is nearly optimal for your problem. If you need more speed, you should use C++ instead.

Comment: Ya you are right. I modified it but it still takes a lot of time so it is better to do it in c++. I have two questions if possible, the first why my problem is o(n^3) complexity while it could be solved by Bfs with O(E+V) complexity. Also which procedure is the best to split the graph (knowing that I've never did that or know about it)

Comment: 1. I was not very correct, it is not O(N^3), it is just cubic. You have N nodes and E edges. For every edge (E) you check all pairs of neighbours, which is `avg(nbrs)^2`. `avg(nbrs)` can be represented as (E/N) so we have `O(E^3/N^2)` with `E >> N`.

Comment: 2. I recommend you to use Gephi software for it. You can use force layouts to look closely on your graph, you can use many analysis functions etc. You also can analyze your graph with networkx (`bridges` , `connectivity` and other types of algorithms).